# How to add text beside a link in HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add text(which is not part of the link) beside a link. How should I align it beside the link?

For example,

text - *link*

I want to do it like that

Comment: Just type it. (This question comes across as something so simple that you really shouldn't need to ask, which suggests that your actual problem is very context sensitive, but you haven't provided any context. You should make an attempt and, if it doesn't work, provide a [mcve])

Comment: Just type it in beside it? It should be that easy, unless you are doing something else - in that case, you need to give us the code you are using and more details of what is going wrong if there are issues doing this.

Comment: I have added an answer. You should also check the Stack Overflow guidelines on how to ask questions and what information to include in your question.

Comment: @ed2 You should also probably check the guidelines on [answer] and what types of questions you should answer (i.e. "well-asked" ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type the text within the element, but not inside the link tag. Your link text will be inside a tag.

For example:

```
<div>Text <a href="#">link</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;" >
<li>Google - <a href="https://www.google.com" >Link</a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Output :

Google - Link